# Other kinds of Codable in Swift 5? (non-JSON Coders)

Tags: swift, codable

Does Apple/Swift 5 provide any other `Codable` serialization implementations out of the box outside of `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder`?

I know I can write my own but I'm thinking for serializing certain things to storage, while JSONEncoder is convenient in that it's human readable I can probably compact it by serializing my objects in binary.

Any time I do a web search for `Codable` protocol every single article talks only about JSON like this is the only way to serialize.

Comment: There is also `PropertyListEncoder`. I believe there is no default binary encoder. `Codable` uses human-readable keys. Binary encoding wouldn't make much sense with such keys. If you want to make it more compact, you can use standard data compression. That's usually a better solution than custom encoding format.

Comment: `PropertyListEncoder` can be used with binary output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895404/propertylistencoder-is-ignoring-binary-outputformat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is `PropertyListEncoder` it's basically xml:

```swift
struct SomeStruct: Codable { let someProperty: String }

try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(SomeStruct(someProperty: "someValue"))
try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(SomeStruct.self, from: data)
```